# Flurry Android SDK proguard.cfg file Configuration issue

Tags: android, flurry, android-proguard

Based on Flurry Android SDK integration [document](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/)

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);(Line 41)
}
```

When I try to build release APK, I am getting below error:

```
on Line 41
flurry android SDK IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type proguard-rules.pro'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. 
In [Flurry Integration Guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/) there is missing `<init>` in theirs proguard script snippets. Just add it this way:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }
```